# How to make a function inside a loop independent of the condition?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Eg.

```
x = 10
y = 20

while x < y:
   x = x + (y - x)
   print(x, y)
```

If I wanted, for example, execute the `print(x, y)`-function regardless of x and y values in loop `while x < y:`, would that be possible in any way? Or is it impossible what I'm asking?

Comment: Fix the indentation first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just print it before the while loop. However if that isn't what you want, you can create two separate variables that serve as x and y's original value, and then print those two original values.

For example:

```
x = 10
y = 20
orig_x = x
orig_y = y

while x < y:
   x = x + (y - x)
   print(orig_x, orig_y)
```

If you only want to print it once, remove the indentation layer on the print statement. Additionally, one more thing, your while loop will only execute once because x = x + (y - x) will only set x to y, so the loop will only iterate once before exiting. Just something to keep in mind.